# C++ variable is nan although the calculation returns a number

Tags: image-processing

When I output m0 to the console it returns "nan" each time but if I output 
the calculation "i * (histProb[i]) / static_cast (w0)" I get numbers ranging from 0 to 0.001 with many decimal places.

Are there too many decimal places for a double to hold or what could the error be?

How can I save the result of the calculation to the variable?

```
float w0 = 0.0;
float w1 = 0.0;
double m0 = 0.0;
float m1 = 0.0;
float mT = 0.0;

float maxVar = 0.0;
float maxVarIndex = 0;

// step through all possible thresholds t = 0 .. 255
for (int t = 0; t < 256; ++t)
{
    // update w and m
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        // todo reset w and m?
        w0 += histProb[i];
        // todo m0 = nan, calc != nan
        m0 += ((i * (histProb[i]) / static_cast<double> (w0)));
        std::cout << m0 << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = t; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        w1 += histProb[i];
        // todo m1 = nan, calc != nan
        m1 += (i * histProb[i] / static_cast<float> (w1));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the first 10 lines of output of your program? I expect that somewhen `((i * (histProb[i]) / static_cast<double> (w0)))` becomes NaN and from then on, m0 is always NaN.

Comment: If `histProp[0]` is 0, then w0 will be 0 in the first iteration, making m0 NaN. Once it's NaN, it'll stay that way through all additions. You should test to make sure w0 is non-zero before you divide by it.

Comment: jep, catching the case that w0 is zero solved the problem, thanks!